# C string pointer. int pointer vs char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I'm wondering why ***p+1** outputs k instead of "o"? I've tried running this with the debugger and still can't seem to figure this out.

```
    char name[] = "john q public";
    int *p = name;
    printf("%c\n", *p+1); // output expected -> o, but got k
    printf("%c", name[0]); // output as expected -> j
```

When I try to output the name in a for loop I get weird values.

```
    int  len = strlen(name);
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++ ){
        printf("%c", *p++); //expected -> john q public, but got -> j ucem n 1 
    }
```

Comment: You should be using a `char *` instead of `int *` in the `p` variable.

Comment: I think it should be printf("%c\n", *(p+1));  to print the second character and in the for loop it will be printf("%c" *(p+i))

Comment: If you put *p+1 first you get *p which is the value for "j" and then j+1 is k. But if you put *(p+1) you increment the address in the memory and then acces the value from that address which is "o"

Comment: Please read your compiler diagnostics messages and add them to the question, the code would have produced a warning in any compliant C compiler despite compiling successfully.

Comment: The solution is to unlearn the `*(x + y)`. It is harder to typo `p[1]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why `'k'`?

You declare:

```
char name[] = "john q public";
```

On access, `name` is converted to a pointer to the first element (a pointer to `'j'`) [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

You assign:

```
int *p = name;
```

So `p` holds as its value the memory location (the address) where `'j'` is stored (e.g. `p` points to `'j'`). Then you print `printf("%c\n", *p+1);` where derefereing `p` (e.g. `*p`) is the character `'j'` and by [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/), `j + 1 == k`, so your output of `'k'` is completely expected.

**j ucem n 1??**

You declare `int *p`, ***Pointer Type Controls Pointer Arithmetic***. So `p++` advances `p` by `sizeof(int)` bytes (typically 4-bytes) instead of `sizeof(char)` bytes (1-byte). So lets look at:

```
    john q public
    -------------
    0123456789012
    ^   ^   ^   ^   4-bytes per p++
    |
    p
```

Incrementing by 4-bytes you have `j uc...` where `...` indicates where you invoke *Undefined Behavior* by accessing memory beyond the end of the `name` array -- all bets are off.

**Always Compile With Warnings Enabled**

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

Had you compiled with warnings enabled, you would have found:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 int *p = name;
```

Comment: Where did you get `j uc...`? Shouldn't it be `q p` and no access beyond the end of `name`? BTW: What does "ucem" mean?

Comment: You might add that dereferencing `*p` is actually `6A6F686E` or `6E686F6A` depending on endianess.

Comment: Points to the `j` and there is undefined behaviour, and the lowest byte is `'j'` and the target architecture happens to be little-endian and and...

Answer (score 3):

A few things that might help:

```
printf("%c\n", *p+1);
```

This is adding 1 to the ascii value of *p, so 'j' + 1 = 'k' (the value you are getting).
What you want is probably:

```
printf("%c\n", *(p+1));
```

Also, you make an int pointer, but I think you want a char pointer in this scenario.

Altogether, this is my suggested edit for getting the first character of a string with pointers:

```
char name[] = "john q public";
char *p = name;
printf("%c\n", *(p));
```

(you don't need the "+1", because arrays start at 0)